Forces on rotating mass from losing counter mass
If you have a massive rotating body, a flywheel with a less massive body attached to it at one point along the edge via some cable or rod etc. what happens to each body if the smaller body is released?
I understand the ballerina analogy about pulling that mass in towards the center or extending it out would speed up or slow down the rotation respectively, but what happens to the flywheel itself when the weight is released?
My line of thinking is that in order for the flywheel to lose momentum it would require the weight to be trusted off and not just released, because it would be receiving the opposing force of the trust. My second thought is in order for it to accelerate faster it would require the mass of the weight to be pulled towards it’s center increasing momentum.
So what happens? Does the flywheel just keep rotating at the same rate? The flywheel needed to impart the energy into the weight to accelerate to its rotational speed, so the energy would be leaving with the weight, but does that mean that once the flywheel reaches that speed the flywheel without the weight is essentially indistinguishable from the flywheel with the weight attached?
I’m also considering the case of equal masses rotating around some attachment media. In that case they would both depart in opposite directions, so if the flywheel is so massive comparatively that its center of mass only moves by some minuscule amount when attached to the weight does that mean it would continue spinning at the same rate but start to travel away from the weight by the amounts relative to their difference in mass?
How would one calculate that, if that’s the case?
